# collating information from variables

Tags: r

```
my_df <- tibble(
  b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA), 
  b2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
  b3 = c(5, 9, 8, NA, 2, 3, 9, 5, NA), 
  b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
  b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
  b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
  b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
  b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
  b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, NA),
  b10 = c(14, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5))
```

Hello,

I have a df like this (a very big df). I want to create a new col (A1- which will come before the other cols) and tell R to look at every row, and for any row that has either 4 OR 8 in it (within cols b3 and b8 only), ask R to write YES in col A1 otherwise write NO-. Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `rowwise`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
my_df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(A1 = ifelse(any(c_across(b3:b8) %in% c(4,8)), 'Yes', 'No'), .before = 1)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 11
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   A1       b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 No        2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14
#> 2 Yes       6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2
#> 3 Yes       3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4
#> 4 No        6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2
#> 5 Yes       4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1
#> 6 Yes       2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1
#> 7 No        1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1
#> 8 No        9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1
#> 9 No       NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_df %>%
  mutate(A1 = pmap_chr(my_df %>% select(b3: b8), ~ {x <- c(...)[!is.na(c(...))];
  c("No", "Yes")[(+any(x %in% c(4, 8)))+1]})) %>%
  relocate(A1)

# A tibble: 9 x 11
  A1       b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 No        2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14
2 Yes       6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2
3 Yes       3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4
4 No        6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2
5 Yes       4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1
6 Yes       2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1
7 No        1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1
8 No        9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1
9 No       NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5
```

Comment: Congrats on the 10k, pmap King

Comment: Thank you very much dear @GuedesBF, hahaha come on that's not true, I am no king, just an ordinary soldier :D

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` with `Reduce` and `Map`

```
my_df$a1 <- c("No", "Yes")[1 + Reduce(`|`, Map(`%in%`,
         my_df[3:8], list(c(4, 8))))]
```

-output

```
my_df$a1
[1] "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "No"  "No"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` in a vectorized way

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
   mutate(a1 = case_when(if_any(b3:b8, `%in%`, c(4, 8)) 
            ~ 'Yes', TRUE  ~'No'), .before = 1)
# A tibble: 9 x 11
  a1       b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 No        2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14
2 Yes       6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2
3 Yes       3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4
4 No        6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2
5 Yes       4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1
6 Yes       2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1
7 No        1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1
8 No        9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1
9 No       NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5
```

Comment: Nice. if_any() is very usefull in these situations. I eventually stoped using the `map%>%reduce` routine after i discovered `if_any()` and `if_all()`

Comment: @GuedesBF check this in the meantime: 
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

Answer (score 2):

You can take help of `rowSums` -

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- my_df %>%
  mutate(a1 = ifelse(rowSums(select(., b3:b8) == 4 | 
             select(., b3:b8) == 8, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, 'Yes', 'No'), .before = 1)
my_df

#  a1       b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 No        2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14
#2 Yes       6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2
#3 Yes       3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4
#4 No        6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2
#5 Yes       4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1
#6 Yes       2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1
#7 No        1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1
#8 No        9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1
#9 No       NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5
```

Comment: Does row 5 satisfy the condition? b3 = 2 and b8 =1, but a1 is 'yes'.

Comment: I am checking for values in column `b3` to `b8`. row 5 has 8 in `b5` and 4 in `b7`.

Comment: Ok! "(within cols b3 and b8 only)" specified by the OP sounds to me more like column b3 and b8 (than `b3` to `b8`).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
my_df$A1 <- ifelse(apply(my_df[,3:8],1,function(x) any(x %in% c(4,8))), 'Yes','No')
my_df
# A tibble: 9 x 11
     b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10 A1   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14 No   
2     6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2 Yes  
3     3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4 Yes  
4     6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2 No   
5     4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1 Yes  
6     2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1 Yes  
7     1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1 No   
8     9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1 No   
9    NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5 No   
my_df <- my_df[, c(11,1:10)]
my_df
# A tibble: 9 x 11
  A1       b1    b2    b3    b4    b5    b6    b7    b8    b9   b10
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 No        2    NA     5    NA     2     9     1    NA     4    14
2 Yes       6     4     9     6    12     2     3     8     5     2
3 Yes       3     6     8    NA     1     4     7     4     7     4
4 No        6     2    NA    10     7     6     7     5     9     2
5 Yes       4     6     2    12     8     7     4     1     5     1
6 Yes       2     6     3     8     5     6     2     4     1     1
7 No        1     1     9     3     5     6     2     1     1     1
8 No        9     1     5     6     6     7     9     3     2     1
9 No       NA     7    NA     2    NA     9     5     6    NA     5
```